# Excel/ Coding language requirement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to figure out if there are any macros in excel for this given task. I want excel to count an number only if it is below certain row height. For example, if in column 1 there are empty rows and then on row 4 there is a number. How could I get excel to count 1, from rows 5 down in a separate column.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTA(A1:A4)`

This formula counts values on a given range. You can tweak it to your needs. In this case, it is counting what has values between `A1` and `A4`.

Play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has different formulas for count functions:
countA(A1:A4) will give you total cells with value.
Countif(A1:A4,">0"), similarly <0 and =0 will give you negative, positive and zero values.
Countblank(A1:A4) will give you the number of blank values.